# How to check validity of PEM certificate issued by CA

Tags: go, x509

I have a certificate (PEM), and I'd like to check if the certificate is valid and signed by CA. I already have the CA certificate (PEM). What is a simple, but secure way to check the certificate in Go, using the standard `crypto/x509` package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`Certificate.Verify()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate.Verify). There is an example for exactly what you want to do in the docs:

https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#example_Certificate_Verify

```
func verifyCert(rootPEM, certPEM string, name string) error {
    roots := x509.NewCertPool()
    ok := roots.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(rootPEM))
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to parse root certificate")
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(certPEM))
    if block == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to parse certificate PEM")
    }
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to parse certificate: %v", err.Error())
    }

    opts := x509.VerifyOptions{
        DNSName: name,
        Roots:   roots,
    }

    if _, err := cert.Verify(opts); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to verify certificate: %v", err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I reorganized it as a function and removed the panics for error handling. The code is otherwise unchanged from the example in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link. In my case, I didn't use `VerifyOptions.DNSName`. Is there any specific reason to (not) use it?

Comment: That depends on your use case. As a general rule, if you are a client you should use it and if you are a server you cannot use it. Using DNSName lets the library validate against all possible names the certificate covers. If you are a client, you know the server you are trying to connect to and therefore should check for a man in the middle attack. If you are a server, chances are you don't know who is connecting and plan to implement your own authorization checks.